# CSS text align side by side and vertical align

Tags: html, css

I have two columns of text side by side. One is right aligned and the other is left aligned.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
.alignleft {
  float: left;
}

.alignright {
  float: right;
}

.list-unstyled {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="store-opening-hours list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      Monday

      <span style="float:right;">9:00 AM - 5:00 PM</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      Tuesday
      <span style="float:right;">9:00 AM - 5:00 PM</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      Wednesday
      <span style="float:right;">9:00 AM - 5:00 PM</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      Thursday
      <span style="float:right;">8:30 AM - 11:00 AM</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="text-align:right;">
      12:30 PM - 2:00 PM
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <b>
       <div style="text-align:left;">
                Friday                
        <span style="float:right;">9:00 AM - 2:30 PM</span>
       </div>
      </b>
  </li>
  <li>
    <b>
       <div style="text-align:right;">
            6:00 PM - 9:00 PM
        </div>
      </b>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      Saturday
      <span style="float:right;">9:00 AM - 5:00 PM</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      Sunday
      <span style="float:right;">Closed</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the Jsfiddle link [JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ct8rmf5u/).

The example above is side by side but the right align text is not vertically aligned as seen in this image:

[image: Final style]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try giving width to your ul. like width: 300px; demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/uqnfztb0/

Comment: @Tushar thanks for the reply but this is not what i want. The right align text is at the extreme right. If you look at the image and check "Closed" then it is right align but it is align with 9:00 Am - 500 PM vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `table` as display properties?

```css
.list-unstyled {
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list-unstyled li {
  display: table-row;
}

.list-unstyled li .weekday {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.list-unstyled li .time {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="store-opening-hours list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <div class="weekday">
      Monday</div>

    <div class="time">9:00 AM - 5:00 PM
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="weekday">
      Tuesday
    </div>
    <div class="time">9:00 AM - 5:00 PM
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="weekday">
      Wednesday
    </div>
    <div class="time">9:00 AM - 5:00 PM</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="weekday">
      Thursday
    </div>
    <div class="time">8:30 AM - 11:00 AM<br>12:30 PM - 2:00 PM</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="weekday">
      <strong>Friday</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="time">9:00 AM - 2:30 PM<br><strong>6:00 PM - 9:00 PM</strong></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="weekday">
      Saturday
    </div>
    <div class="time">9:00 AM - 5:00 PM
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="weekday">
      Sunday
    </div>
    <div class="time">Closed
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use table instead

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="200">Monday</td>
    <td>9:00AM - 5:00PM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>9:00AM - 5:00PM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>9:00AM - 5:00PM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>8:30AM - 11:00AM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><b>Friday</b></td>
    <td><b>9:00AM - 2:30PM</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>6:00PM - 9:00PM</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Saturday</td>
    <td>9:00AM - 5:00PM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sunday</td>
    <td>Closed</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Working Demo**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="200">Monday</td>
    <td>9:00AM - 5:00PM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>9:00AM - 5:00PM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>9:00AM - 5:00PM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>8:30AM - 11:00AM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><b>Friday</b></td>
    <td><b>9:00AM - 2:30PM</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>6:00PM - 9:00PM</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Saturday</td>
    <td>9:00AM - 5:00PM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sunday</td>
    <td>Closed</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: is it not possible to use the <li>? i dont want to use <table> because the example i have given is a HTML generated of my code. In order to make changes from <li> to <table> i would need to do alot of changes

Comment: Use table only if its a tabular data. Don't use it for design. Use divs and align with CSS.

Comment: i'm not sure but i think you can use grid system too

Comment: +1 @OwaisAhmed if you can modify it to be a table, it's honestly the best option. Keeps it simple and is an ideal use of `<table>`. Other options are just creating a more complicated table.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do this by adding span class to the timing and days. These spans have a fixed width so that the text aligned.

```
<ul class="store-opening-hours list-unstyled">
    <li>
        <div>
            <span class="days">Monday</span>
            <span class="timings">9:00 AM - 5:00 PM</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span class="days">Tuesday</span>
            <span class="timings">9:00 AM - 5:00 PM</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span class="days">Wednesday</span>
            <span class="timings">9:00 AM - 5:00 PM</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span class="days">Thursday</span>
            <span class="timings">8:30 AM - 11:00 AM</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span class="days"><br></span>
            <span class="timings">12:30 PM - 2:00 PM</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <b>
            <div>
                <span class="days">Friday</span>
                <span class="timings">9:00 AM - 2:30 PM</span>
            </div>
        </b>
    </li>
    <li>
        <b>
            <div>
                <span class="days"><br></span>
                <span class="timings"> 6:00 PM - 9:00 PM</span>
            </div>
        </b>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span class="days">Saturday</span>
            <span class="timings">9:00 AM - 5:00 PM</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>

            <span class="days">Sunday</span>
            <span class="timings">Closed</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```css
.list-unstyled {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.days {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

.timings {
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}
```

[Working code](https://jsfiddle.net/_3lok/7nLasqrb/)